# how to pass value of a key by index in a dictionary from grid view to next view by navigation link in swiftui

Tags: ios, json, swiftui, gridview

Here I have a dictionary where keys are the categories of a grocery shop like vegetables and fruits etc..and values are the dictionary of the items of that category and its details.
I was listed the category name in my home page and I want to navigate to the next view with the items of selected category from homepage.what did do for this.
Anyone please help me.

```
import SwiftUI
import Kingfisher
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var groceryViewModel : ProductViewModel
    let columns : [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()),count: 3)
    var body: some View {
        let Keys = Array(groceryViewModel.prodType.keys)
        let typeKeys = groceryViewModel.prodType.map{key in
            return key
        }
         var indexes = groceryViewModel.prodType.keys.map { groceryViewModel.prodType.index(forKey: $0) }
        
            
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView{
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns,spacing: 10) {
                    
                    ForEach(Keys,id: \.self){ item in
                        VStack(alignment: .center,spacing: 4){
                            Spacer()
                            NavigationLink(destination: ProductListView(groceryViewModel: ProductViewModel(), item: item) /*ProductListView(groceryViewModel: ProductViewModel())*/,label:{
                                VStack {
                                    Image(item)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .clipShape(Circle())
                                        .scaledToFill()
                                        .frame(width:
                                                100,height: 100)
                                        
                                    Text(item)
                                        .font(.system(.headline,weight: .bold))
                                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            
                      )
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                    
                    
                    .onAppear {
                        groceryViewModel.readJSONFile(filename: "Groceries")
                    }
               }
             .navigationBarTitle(Text("Categories"),displayMode: .inline)
        }
     }
}
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View{
        ContentView(groceryViewModel: ProductViewModel())
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You need to merge your two arrays into one and iterate over that new array

Answer (score 0):

To navigate from a grid to the next view with values of a particular String, pass the String to the navigation title of the next view, you could use the NavigationLink view in SwiftUI for this. In the ForEach loop that displays the grid, you can wrap each item in a NavigationLink and pass the corresponding String as a parameter to the next view. Here's an example:

```
 ForEach(groceryViewModel.prodType.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: ProductListView(groceryViewModel: ProductViewModel(), category: item)) {
        Text(item)
            .font(.system(.headline, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

In the above code, ProductListView is the next view that you want to navigate to, and category is a parameter of type String that you want to pass to the next view. You can then use this parameter to display the corresponding values in the next view and set the navigation title. Here's an example of how you can set the navigation title in the next view:

```
struct ProductListView: View {
    let groceryViewModel: ProductViewModel
    let category: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Display the values of the selected category here
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(category), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

category is the parameter that you passed from the previous view, and you can use it to set the navigation title using the navigationBarTitle modifier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can u please tell me how to display the values of selected category?

Comment: Can You please tell me about the data transferring to next view of the selected category from the content view